# android - stop receiving location updates

Tags: android, google-maps, location

In my android app, I am using the code below to get user's current location.

```
private void getDeviceLocation() {
    Boolean mLocationPermissionGranted = //ask for permission and stuff
    if (mLocationPermissionGranted) {   //if permission granted
        mCurrentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }
}
```

I only want 1 location update so I `removeLocationUpdates` inside my `onLocationChanged` method.

```
 @Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mCurrentLocation = location;
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
}
```

Doing that stops calling the `onLocationChanged` method but I see on the map that my location still keeps changing ever few seconds. The accuracy radius keeps increasing or decreasing. I don't want that. I want the "blue dot" to be stable and not moving.

Comment: You may have used `mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);`. This feature let the Google Map access user's location without more code from you. It can be useful, as it can not.

Comment: @Gorcyn ya, I have used `setMyLocationEnabled(true)` but setting it to false only removes the "blue dot". The issue is still there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the blue dot has own location source. After setting`setMyLocationEnabled(true)` it will start to pinpoint your location. **So, the blue dot has nothing to do with your location request.**

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#setMyLocationEnabled) says for MyLocationLayer(blue dot)

> While enabled and the location is available, the my-location layer
>   continuously draws an indication of a user's current location

Means, whenever the MyLocationLayer receive new location, the blue dot will move.

But there is a way to change this behavior : `setLocationSource (LocationSource source)`

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#setLocationSource(com.google.android.gms.maps.LocationSource)) says for setLocationSource

> Replaces the location source of the my-location layer.

Means, you can integrate your location request and behavior(only one location as you wish) to the blue dot(MyLocationLayer)

Check this [sample](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/MapsV2/Location/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/mapsv2/location/MainActivity.java), exactly does what you need